# XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://localhost/Test/TestService.asmx Line Number 1, Column 1:

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, asmx

I created a Web service in VS 2008 and hosted it in IIS but when trying to oprn it in brwoser it throws this error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't open it in a browser. Write a unit test to call the service. How the service behaves in the browser may not be how it behaves in real life.
2. Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to watch the network traffic. You'll see interesting things.
3. I bet the reason you've got an XML parsing error is that XML isn't what's being returned from the server. I bet you've got text or HTML telling you there's been an error in your web service.